# Artisan command not recognized

Tags: php, laravel, cmd, xampp, laravel-artisan

I am trying to do `artisan update`. It says that the command `artisan` is not recognized as a command. I am using xampp, so I have added PATH to `c:\xampp\php` but this command is still not working. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: you need to execute the artisan commands in your root of your application

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that there is an artisan command called update unless this is from something like a package. what you would need to do is `cd` into the application directory where you would see the artisan file if you would list the files using 'ls' and run it via `php artisan update`, having the php in your path will only give you the ability to execute the php command and its functions globally without having to reference the full path. what i believe you are looking for is not artisan update you probably are looking for **`composer update`** those two are different and you must understand that composer and artisan are totally different commands Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

I'ts simple:

- Navigate to the directory of artisan, because you can have multiple Laravel installations with an artisan version
- Run `php artisan update`

Answer (score 1):

You can only do artisan commands from your project folder.

In your case do:

```
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\projectfolder or 'path' where is your project
```

then `artisan update`